# How do I avoid "Stop code: DRIVER PNP WATCHDOG" when trying to install Windows 10?

Tags: windows, windows-10, hard-drive, boot

I am trying to install Windows 10 on a desktop computer that someone else built at my work. Every time I try to boot from the installation disk, it shows the Window logo then a loading icon and returns the following error:

```
Your PC ran into a problem and needs to restart. We'll restart for you.
For more information about this issue and possible fixes, visit https://www.windows.com/stopcode
If you call a support person, give them this info:
Stop code: DRIVER PNP WATCHDOG
```

...and then the computer restarts.

So far, I have tried:

- Making bootable media (USB) using Windows Media Creation Tool and Rufus with a Windows 10 ISO.
- Making bootable media with UEFI bios option and MBR partition option.
- Booting from USB using F10 to select boot media or by changing boot order so that removable media is first.
- Installing on hard drive with old Windows 10 image on it, overwriting hard drive with zeroes, reformatting hard drive with NTFS partition, and reformatting hard drive with FAT partition.
- Toggling on and off BIOS settings pertaining to boot or USB.
- Resetting BIOS to default settings.
- Tried using multiple USB drives as the bootable media.

Every combination of these options I have tried returns the same error for me.

Comment: The installation disk may be corrupt.